# css for ie without using conditional comments

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I came to know about these styles for IE specific:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* IE10-specific styles go here */  
}

@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {  
    /* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */  
}
```

I wanted to know for other versions of ie too.

How can I use media query for ie6 only, ie7 only, ie8 only, ie9 only, less than or equal to ie10, etc.?

Is there any other hacks?

Comment: What is "conditional formatting"?

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake I meant to be conditional comment..

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support media queries in versions 8 and below - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)

This means that any code within media queries will be ignored by IE8-

So no, you can't use media queries to target older versions of IE.

**However...**

there are other hacks available in css to target older version of IE....

Here's an excerpt of [this css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/):

```
/* IE6 */
#once { _color: blue }

/* IE6, IE7 */
#doce { *color: blue; /* or #color: blue */ }

/* Everything but IE6 */
#diecisiete { color/**/: blue }

/* IE6, IE7, IE8 */
#diecinueve { color: blue\9; }

/* IE7, IE8 */
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }

/* IE6, IE7 -- acts as an !important */
#veintesiete { color: blue !ie; } /* string after ! can be anything */
```

Comment: That I already saw. But wanted to know like using media query as in my question. thanks though.